# What Is "Blow-Out" In The Research Context For An Academic

Tags: research-process

A junior academic in a department I was doing research in once said to me in reference to a senior member of the department that "Prof X no longer does research, just course design and teaching. He was involved in fascinating fundamental work in the 1960s but had a research blow-out some years ago."

At the time I must admit I read this as a euphemism for research idleness on the part of Prof X. To me then nothing could be more exciting than going further and further in research, one thing always leading to another - even if one had some teaching to do or had to write an occasional textbook.
About a year later during a conversation with Prof X (temporarily acting HoD till a new chap was appointed) on what really constituted the essence of a PhD, I was shown Prof X's own thesis from the late 1950s. He offered this as an example of a study with no industrial application whatever, performed on a material one might almost describe as a domestic material but which nonetheless illuminated some of the fundamental processes involved in dislocation movement and plastic flow. I took his point.

Till lately - when Google Scholar and UK Theses Online allowed it - I could not readily validate the claims for Prof X's early research distinction. Now I can and see that it was substantial till the late 1970s. Then a complete stop in his publications bar course related textbooks.

Is there such a thing as research blow-out ? Or is it a term for mental/emotional strain leading to a more detached or disinterested attitude to research - or something else entirely different ?

Comment: It's surely not a standard term and your best bet would be to ask the junior academic for a little more explanation.

Comment: I thought it just meant cruising along at a nice clip, then having a metaphorical tire blow out, thus ending the productive aspect of the endeavor. Definite a set back, but possibly not permanent.

Comment: Is it an old term for burnout, perhaps?

Comment: The guy got his PhD in the late 1950s? He must be at least eighty years old by now -- maybe he just wants a rest!

Comment: Like @astronat commented, are you sure Prof X isn't emeritus/retired and just doing what he wants now?

Comment: "Prof X's own thesis from the late 1950s"
"it was substantial till the late 1970s".
20 years of substantial career! show some respect.
I will be rude: I think the junior academic has some deep issues, that he/she does not realize how there is a life outside academica or he/she has way too much expectations (from him/herself and from her/his peers).

Comment: I believe some English-language prints of the film "La Grande Bouffe" bore the title "The Blow-Out", but I'm not sure where that takes us in terms of interpreting "research blow-out".

Comment: @EarlGrey It was said with respect, not otherwise. That junior member had only one issue - talking too much. Otherwise very competent. Personally I've no issue with focus on education by faculty of that age-group. But I wonder if Prof X would be given such scope in today's academia ("We Are A Research Led University", etc) for non-activity in research. His 1960s papers are cited by hundreds of researchers in his area of research.

Comment: @mkennedy : Conversation with junior lecturer occurred in late 1988. Prof X's PhD was published in 1959. So By 1978 when his research dried up, he'd have been in his mid-40s. But his course books were being published up to the early 1990s.

Answer (score 11):

Let's not focus on the exact meaning of "blow out" (which can be interpreted as an explosion, but also as in "blowing out a candle") and instead what might lead to people's research fizzling out. There are many reasons I've seen among my colleagues:

- They discover what they really like: Maybe writing textbooks is your colleague's true passion and something they are good at. So they focus on that.
- They have a difficult family life -- say, a disabled child, or caring for aging parents -- and make the decision (voluntary or not) that they need to spend more time on that than on their research.
- They are very good at a small area of research but that area dies over time. For example, they may have been very good at building better vacuum tubes in the 1950s to 1970s and may continue to be very good at that, but the invention of the transistor led to their area to be more and more of a niche area with fewer and fewer publication and funding options.
- They turn out to be good administrators and organizers, and so focus on running the faculty council, the graduate program of the department, or be department head, to the detriment of their research.
- They decided that their current salary is good and that they really enjoy playing tennis. So they do what's strictly necessary for keeping their job (teach, do some administration) for 30 or 35 hours a week, play tennis, and other than that accept that their pay raises will be lower than they could be if they spent an extra 20 hours a week on research.

That last point could be interpreted as "laziness", but in the end, I think it's worthwhile keeping in mind that to run a university/the research enterprise as a whole, it takes all sorts of people. Not everyone has to be a crack researcher and it is not useful to measure every professor by the standard template you seem to have in mind.

Comment: Point #2 is relevant I think. He didn't care too much for how much or how little people did beyond the necessary seminars, etc. And he was genuinely sure to make sure research grant salary got through. Another thing is that he was bounced into becoming Head of Department due to the accidental death of the previous HoD in 1970. It was a new department in a new university so he must have been *seriously* busy. But a lot of latitude was also given in that campus for home study leave for book writing.

Answer (score 4):

A "blow-out" in this context is either:

1. a (I think primarily NA English) reference to a severe conflict, usually used to describe an argument escalated to the point where one or both parties are shouting or yelling at the other. It can also refer to
2. a mechanical failure involving a pressure release, like failure of a tire or oil well.

In either case, the use of the phrase in the context you refer to seems to be a metaphor referring to these uses of the term: either they had a strong conflict with their research (not necessarily an interpersonal one, but with the "research" itself standing as the other party), or some mechanical failure that blocked progress.

I don't think there is any *euphemism* here, which would suggest hiding or covering up some darker sin. To say an academic has had a blow-out with their research is to say they've had a major conflict or hit a major stumbling block. The nature of that conflict is unclear - maybe they got burnt out on a particular problem they could not solve, maybe they worked hard on a solution they were confident in only to find that an error some time back made all subsequent work flawed, maybe they just reevaluated and decided they weren't enjoying it.

In this case, they've responded by completely backing away from research and focusing on other areas. "Idleness" implies laziness; there's nothing lazy about making a decision to stop pursuing research. Yes, this may be somewhat unusual at a research-focused academic institution, but some people simply choose to move on but still like other parts of the academic experience like educating others.

Comment: I think you mean “blow-up”.

Comment: @Buffy No, I do not, I mean "blow-out" as the question asks. #6 here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blowout I agree they can be used somewhat interchangeably, though, at least in US English.

Comment: I never heard that usage, actually.

Comment: @Buffy Maybe it's a more recent usage, but I wouldn't consider it particularly unusual or niche. It's difficult to follow with say Ngram since there are so many other uses of the term, including hair styles.

Comment: Hmmm. And parties. Not since last March, though. Alas.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are two possible, but opposite, meanings, though I think the second one is what is intended here.

But a blow out could actually mean an especially important advance in a field. Einstein-like.

The other meaning is probably an extreme form of burn out where someone just decides that there was enough pressure for a long enough time and they just want to do something else. But that something else could also be important in the wider scheme of things. Course design and teaching, especially by people with distinguished careers in research can be valuable both personally and to the institution and its students.

And, a burn out scenario immediately following a vast and intense advance in the field would be pretty natural. So, one of the meanings might apply and be immediately followed by the other.

Doctoral students also have a tendency to burn out at some point, just due to the pressure. Research isn't like cutting grass.

Comment: "Research isn't like cutting grass" - no, more like "blowing grass" ;-) It goes in all directions and you get frustrated, which of the various gusts of grass leaves to follow...